# offset in bootstrap for column

Tags: html, offset, bootstrapping

I would like to ask why offset in container-fluid, first row doesn't work. If you resize your browser to the minimum, you will see first row - number 0 is overriding the offset space. Can you let me know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

             <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-2" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">0</div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">4</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">5</div>


        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">6</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">7</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">8</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">9</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">10</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">11</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">12</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">13</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">14</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1" style="border-style:double;border-color:black;">15</div>


        </div>




    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should work. Offset works as a blank column placed before your column. Your offset has a size of 2 columns.